# Select a part of Excel Cell (Not Complete Cell) and convert it to Uppercase by running a macro

Tags: excel, vba

Select a part of Excel Cell (Not Complete Cell) and convert it to Uppercase by running a macro.

I have a piece of code which will convert a selected cell or selected range of cells to Uppercase, but my requirement is, Selection will be a part (Sub String) of a cell and it should be converted to uppercase if I execute the macro.

For example, I have a cell with value "Thanks for Helping"

Now my code is:

```
Convert_To_Upper()
Selection.value = UCase(Selection.Value)
end Sub
```

If user selects the cell and runs the macro, cell will be changed to "THANKS FOR HELPING"

Now my requirement is..

If user selects only "Helping" from the cell and Runs the macro cell should be changed to "Thanks for HELPING"

Is it possible achieve this?

Comment: Can you please add print screen of your excel Sheet and your attempt too.

Comment: Sory I dont Knw how to add a print screen here... But I'm using excel 2003 and it does not contain any formulas...

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want to click a cell, select part of the string by marking it with the mouse pointer and then run a macro that converts that to upper case. If that is the case, I'm pretty sure it is not possible since the selection is cleared when you execute a macro

Comment: Your understanding is perfect... Selection is not getting cleared if assigning the macro to a Menu Item.. will that help..?

Comment: You can't run a macro while a cell is in Edit mode. @JonCarlstedt is right. It can't be done, at least the way you are thinking of it.

Answer (score 1):

In short: No, it cant be done.

An **extremely ugly hack** to *kind of* fix it is the following:

Get the user to select the text and hit CTRL+C to copy it to clipboard, then run macro.

Pull string from clipboard to a variable (you have to add MSForms Reference)

```
'Clipboard -> variable S
Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
Dim S As String
DataObj.GetFromClipboard
S = DataObj.GetText
```

remove that from the text in the cell with some kind of diff or regex, convert it to upper and concat it with the cell.

It gets it done, but it is not exactly best practice...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Private Sub test()

    ' n is the number of letter you want to have to upper case
    n = 2

    Cells(1, 1) = UCase(Left(Cells(1, 1), n)) + Mid(Cells(1, 1), n + 1)

End Sub
```

UCase(string) = transform a string to upper case

Left(string, int) = take the first int characters of string starting from the left side

Cells(x,y) = returns a Cell in position (x,y)

Mid(string, int) = returns the content of a string starting from the character in position int

Comment: Sorry its selecting only first 2 Characters and changing into Uppercase.

Comment: I added some explanation and a parameter. Hope now it's more clear

Comment: For your better understanding lets take a cell with value "Good Luck" At some instance user select "Good" and run a Macro, "Good" should be changed to "GOOD" if he selects "od Luc" and runs a macro it should be

Answer (score 0):

You can pick part of the string in a cell with MID

```
Dim var As String
var = Mid(ActiveCell.Text, 1, 10)
```

Mid(string, start, number of characters you want)

EDIT:

So, the user needs to select how many characters to change:

```
'Throw up a popup box
numbVar= InputBox(Prompt:="Please input how many characters to turn into UPPER", _
          Title:="Anything goes here", Default:="Enter number here")

' Exit if cancel is pressed
If numbVar= "" Then Exit Sub
```

then put numbVar instead of 10

Comment: Nice, but selection will not be constant always, its should be up to the user that how many characters he want to change to uppercase.

Comment: That was not part of the question, but ask the user for that and put it in a variable and use that instead of 10

Comment: But is there any way to automatically identify the user selection. For Eg. Selection.value = UCase(Selection.value).

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for here.Please edit your original question with the code you have and what you need it to do.